# How to get the path of the jruby/warbler jar file

Tags: java, ruby, jruby, warbler

I'm building an application using JRuby and Warbler to package it. My problem is that I want to get the path of the jar file that is currently running, without writing java...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `RbConfig::CONFIG["bindir"]` have what you want?

```
$ java -cp Development/src/jruby/lib/jruby-complete.jar org.jruby.Main -e 'require "rbconfig"; p RbConfig::CONFIG["bindir"]'
"file:/Users/asari/Development/src/jruby/lib/jruby-complete.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/bin"
```